# Create textarea with same style as angular validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea

I'm working on an angularjs project, and currently I'm in the form validation phase. I know that textareas don't work the same as `<input>`s do, but is it possible to get the same rounded corner? And if possible the same red border when it's invalid?

[image: ex: 1]

[image: example]

Specifically rounded corners, and the glow effect. I'm wanting to keep the look of my page uniform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what i was doing wrong, as I am new to html and css I didn't realize the class that I was calling. I simply needed to add `class="form-control"` to my `<input>`. This doesn't fix dynamically creating a red border when the input is invalid unfortunately.